# onclick event is not firing in anchor tag in firefox 4.1

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
 var ni =  document.getElementById("fileDiv");
 var objFileCount = document.getElementById("fileCount");
 var num = (document.getElementById("fileCount").value - 1) + 2;
 objFileCount.value = num;

 var newdiv = document.createElement("div");

 var divIdName = "file" + num + "Div";
 newdiv.id = divIdName;
 //newdiv.setAttribute("id", divIdName);

 newdiv.innerHTML = '<input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment"/> <a name="#"  onclick="removeFile(' + divIdName + ');" style="color:blue;cursor:pointer;">Remove</a> ';
 ni.appendChild(newdiv);



 function removeFile(divName) {
           alert(divName);

           var d = document.getElementById("fileDiv");
           d.removeChild(divName);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the quotes for the divIdName:

```
newdiv.innerHTML = '<input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment"/> <a name="#"  onclick="removeFile(\'' + divIdName + '\');" style="color:blue;cursor:pointer;">Remove</a> ';
```

Also, please elaborate more on your problem when posting a question; don't just post the code and expect an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply skoshy. But the problem is yet to be solved. when i run the same code in IE 8 it works well. but what i have noticed here in firefox 4.1 is that newdiv.innerhtml wont accept the onclick event handler and errorconsole tells file1div is undefined. as i have to remove the file onclick of remove link of anchor but the function removeFile(removeFile(divName)) { } wont accept the divName value to remove the child div.